# Can you purchase a ship to win your final Fame Point?

Tags: xia

In Xia: Legends of a Drift System, there are many ways to gain Fame.  One of them is to purchase it, at the cost of 5,000 credits per fame point.  However, the rulebook explicitly states that you cannot purchase your final fame point in this manner.  Another way to gain fame is to purchase a new ship.

Is there anything preventing a player from purchasing a new ship for 5,000 credits and receiving his final Fame point in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can win by purchasing a ship (upgrade to a higher tier). As you stated, the only method of gaining points that you are forbidden to use to win the game is buying 1 point for 5,000 credits. Other than that, anything goes